# Upgraded code is coming up with a new error

Tags: acumatica

I've upgraded customization code from 6.5  to 2019 R2.   I have the following BQL that worked fine before, yet now is giving me errors:  The code is as follows:

```
PXResultset<xvwInterCompanyProcess> res = PXSelect<xvwInterCompanyProcess,
                                          Where<xvwInterCompanyProcess.origRefNbr, Equal<Required<xvwInterCompanyProcess.origRefNbr>>>>.Select(new PXGraph<ARDocumentRelease>(), arinvoice.RefNbr);
```

where xvwInterCompanyProcess is a DAC for a view.

The errors I'm getting when I try to evaluate 'res' are:

- Single row was requested
- Evaluation requires a thread to run temporarily. Use the Watch window to perform the evaluation.

If I try to do a count on the res variable, I get the following:

- Count:  The function evaluation requires all threads to run.

I have no idea why this would have worked previously, but not comes up with this error...

Comment: Does it happen even when debugger is not attached? I mean do you get same error in Acumatica trace?

Answer (score -2):

Don't create an instance of a graph using new. Use PXGraph.CreateInstance.

Or use the this graph if you can

Comment: This is a good observation and should have been posted as a comment, not an answer, as it does not solve the issue.

Comment: And how do you know that it doesn't solve the issue? Did you test the code?